# How to monitor the postfix mail queue using monit?

Tags: postfix, monitoring, monit

Is there a way to monitor the postfix mail queue using monit? the available scripts just check, up/down/memory or CPU.  I would like notices when the queue starts filling up. it would be nice to be able to set monitors on the different queues to be able to react appropriately.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have to use the "program" feature of Monit.

If your `monitrc` file includes `include /etc/monit.d/*.cfg`, then in your `/etc/monit.d`, create a `.cfg` file with the content (add the appropriate include statement in your `monitrc` file if you don't include all `*.cfg` files in `/etc/monit.d`)

```
check program mail-queue path "/usr/local/sbin/check_postfix_queue"
    if status != 0 then alert
```

Then create the script `/usr/local/sbin/check_postfix_queue` with this content:

```
#!/bin/bash

MAXMSG=20
MSG=$( postqueue -p | egrep '\-\- [0-9]+ Kbytes in [0-9]+ Request[s]*\.' | awk '{ print $5 }'  )
[ ${MSG:-0} -le $MAXMSG ] && exit 0 || exit 1
```

MAXMSG is the message queue limit: if number of messages is above that parameter, monit emits an alert.

Comment: very similar to the qmail process/script

Answer (score 0):

Here is my version of **check_postfix_queue** script. It does not call `mailq` command, because it reads and lists all messages from all queues, but we want to know just the number of messages.

It also shows number of messages per queue.

```sh
#!/bin/bash
# usage: mailq-check.sh [<max-count>]

TOTAL=0

for QUEUE in maildrop hold incoming active deferred; do
    CNT=$(find /var/spool/postfix/$QUEUE -type f | wc -l)
    TOTAL=$(( TOTAL + CNT ))
    echo $QUEUE: $CNT
done

echo total: $TOTAL

if [ -n "$1" ] && [ "$TOTAL" -gt "$1" ]; then
    exit 1
fi

exit 0
```

Optional parameter can set max. number of messages in all queues that triggers error.

You can use this script in monit as mentioned in the first answer:

```
check program mail-queue path "/usr/local/sbin/check_postfix_queue 50"
    if status != 0 then alert
```